# How can i create a retrofit api method call that doesnt return a response

Tags: java, android, retrofit2

I am trying to create an api call that doesn't have a response  with retrofit, but the call does not return any thing, so how do i handle it in Retrofit

i have a code like this :

```
    @POST("/message")
public Call<ResponseModel> SendMessageToSocketIOServer(@Body SocketIOMessageModel socketIOMessageModel);
```

but i tried this using void but with no result

```
 @POST("/message")
public Call<void> SendMessageToSocketIOServer(@Body SocketIOMessageModel socketIOMessageModel);
```

So how can i achieve handling a no response call api ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just change `Call<void>` to `Call<Void>` (with uppercase V). All generic expect reference type, not primitive type or void.

Answer (score 1):

You can use `Call<ResponseBody>` .Which indicates that you doesn't care about response body. But you can check the response is successful.